# Set DataGridTextBoxColumn DataProperty to a member of an array c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to set the DataProperty property of a DataGridTextBoxColumn to an element of an array. However, the value is not displaying on the datagridview. I have configured other columns whose DataProperty is not set to a member of an array and they display values correctly.

The code I'm using to set up the columns that display data from elements of an array is as follows.

```
        // generate multiple load height columns
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn[] loadCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn[dataCollection.part.numLoadHeightValues];
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn[] heightCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn[dataCollection.part.numLoadHeightValues];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataCollection.part.numLoadHeightValues; i++) {
            //load columns
            loadCol[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            loadCol[i].Name = "loadCol" + (i + 1);
            loadCol[i].HeaderText = "Load " + (i + 1);
            loadCol[i].DataPropertyName = "loadValues["+i+"]";
            //height columns
            heightCol[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            heightCol[i].Name = "heightCol" + (i + 1);
            heightCol[i].HeaderText = "Height " + (i + 1);
            heightCol[i].DataPropertyName = "heightValues["+i+"]";
        }

        //add load and height columns
        for (int i = 0; i < dataCollection.part.numLoadHeightValues; i++) {
            serialConDataGrid.Columns.Add(loadCol[i]);
            serialConDataGrid.Columns.Add(heightCol[i]);
        }
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: I don't think this will work with arrays. What is your heightValues array?

Comment: @Moop The heightValues array and the loadValues array store decimal elements. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Take a look at this one and virtual mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505626/dataggridviewcolumn-datapropertyname-to-an-array-element

Comment: @Moop I used virtual mode similar to the example in that link and it worked for me, thanks!